# Does the least squares algorithm require unique x values?

Tags: least-squares

In the code here
http://dracoblue.net/dev/linear-least-squares-in-javascript/
for the x values input, does anyone know if the function works if the x values array has duplicate values?

Comment: It should work for duplicate values.  But, you do need different values to prevent divide by zero.

Comment: if I happen to get duplicate x values, then how would I handle that, should I just convert it to 1 x value by averaging it's y values?

Comment: As long as the X values aren't *all* the same, no special precautions would be needed.

Comment: So if the x values are for example [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] then that's ok? and if its [2, 2, 2, 2] then that would cause a divide by zero?

Comment: @Omega Yes, that's correct.